# Returning the PK during a linq to sql insert

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I want to return the PK ID when I insert a new user via linq to sql.

how can I do this? i.e. is there anything built in or do I have to do 2 queries?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do anything.  Just check the PK field on the object you used to create it after you've done a `SubmitChanges()`.  LINQ to SQL autopopulates it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DB-generated ID field then it will be enough to set the Auto Generated Value property to True and the AutoSync property to OnInsert for this field in the model designer.